# Cannot assign to a property of an instance that get returned from a get-only subscript

Tags: swift

I return an instance from a get-only subscript, but I cannot assign to a property of the returned instance

```
struct Student {
    var id: String
    var attendance = 0
    var absence = 0
}

class StudentStore {
    var students = [Student]()
    subscript(id: String) -> Student? {
        students.first(where: { $0.id == id } )
    }
}

var studentStore = StudentStore()

var newStudent = Student(id: "2014901001")
studentStore.students.append(newStudent)

studentStore["2014901001"]?.attendance = 1 // error: Cannot assign to property: subscript is get-only
```

Comment: Well no, because `Student` is a struct and has value semantics. How about making `Student` a class instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
studentStore["2014901001"]?.attendance = 1
```

You are trying to set one of the `Student` objects in the `students` array, aren't you?

However, the subscript getter doesn't return (a reference to) one of the objects in the `students` array. Due to the value semantics of the `Student` struct, you return a *copy* of the `Student` object that is in the `students` array. You can't achieve what you want if you just set the `attendance` of that copy. Therefore, the Swift compiler compiles your code to something like this:

```
let copy = studentStore["2014901001"]
copy?.attendance = 1
studentStore["2014901001"] = copy
```

You can see that it *sets* the setter with the modified copy again. But your subscript does not have a setter, which is where the error comes from.

To solve this, you can make `Student` a class, which has reference semantics. This enables you to return the `Student` object that is in the `students` array, allowing the caller of the subscript to set their attendance.

```
class Student {
    var id: String
    var attendance = 0
    var absence = 0
    
    init(id: String, attendance: Int = 0, absence: Int = 0) {
        self.id = id
        self.attendance = attendance
        self.absence = absence
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a setter. However, that would allow nonsense like this:

```
studentStore["1"] = Student(id: "2")
```

You need to decide what you want to happen here.

Comment: I forgot that struct is a value type. I used class instead and it works.

Answer (score 4):

The subscription doesn't have a `set`ter. What you have is the implicit `get`ter which is a short form of

```
subscript(id: String) -> Student? {
    get {
        students.first(where: { $0.id == id } )
    }
}
```

But it's impossible to update a value type item in an array with key subscription anyway.

An alternative is to add an update function to the store which takes the `id`, a `keyPath` and a `value`

```
func updateStudent<Value>(withID id: String, keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Student,Value>, value: Value) {
    guard let index = students.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == id}) else { return }
    students[index][keyPath: keyPath] = value
}
```

Getting the index is mandatory to be able to modify the item in the array directly.

---

Then you can replace

```
studentStore["2014901001"]?.attendance = 1
```

with

```
studentStore.updateStudent(withID: "2014901001", keyPath: \.attendance, value:1)
```

Comment: Yes I forgot that struct is a value type, but also no need for a set in the subscript because I just want to get the Student instance through the get, then assign to instance properties through dot syntax.